# Reference for redundance of inversion condition for Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

The definition of a Lie group is that its multiplication and also the map that sends $g$ to $g^{-1}$ are differentiable maps. It is known that the inversion condition is redundant, using the Implicit Function Theorem.

Q1) I would like to ask if there are any books / notes describing it in the simplest possible way. (Reference request) If anyone can put their proof here it will be good too.

I have read [this](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57bf2a6de3df281593b7f57d/t/57bf694bf7e0abe0fdca04d3/1472162123845/inversion.pdf), and unfortunately I do not really understand it, though admittedly it looks short and neat. Is there a simpler way to prove that inversion is redundant, or is that the simplest proof already?

This is a question in Brocker and tom Dieck, which unfortunately I believe cannot be solved using the material covered in the book alone.

Thanks!

Note: I have read [Redundance of the Smoothness of the Inversion Map in the Definition of a Lie Group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301221/redundance-of-the-smoothness-of-the-inversion-map-in-the-definiton-of-a-lie-grou), to no avail as well.

Q2) Also, what version of Implicit Function Theorem is being used in the proof? After some research, I am pretty sure it is not this version in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), but not sure which is the most appropriate version to use.

Answer (score 17):

Let
$$F:G\times G\to G\times G\quad F(g,h)=(g,gh).$$
Then, $F$ is a smooth map since multiplication is assumed to be smooth.

> **Lemma.** The differential of $F$ at a point $(g,h)\in G\times G$ is given by
>   $$(dF)_{(g,h)}:T_gG\times T_hG\to T_gG\times T_{gh}G,\quad (X,Y)\mapsto (X,(dR_h)_g(X)+(dL_g)_h(Y)),\tag{1}$$
>   where $R_h:G\to G$ is right multiplication by $h$ and $L_g:G\to G$ left multiplication by $g$.

*Proof:* This is an easy exercise.

The map $L_g:G\to G$ has a smooth inverse $L_{g^{-1}}$, so it is a diffeomorphism. Thus, $(dL_g)_h$ is an isomorphism and hence $(1)$ is surjective. Since the domain and range have the same dimension, $(1)$ is an isomorphism. This shows that $F$ is a local diffeomorphism. But $F$ is also bijective, so we have shown:

> **Lemma.** The map $F$ is a diffeomorphism.

In particular, its inverse
$$F^{-1}:G\times G\to G\times G,\quad F^{-1}(g,h)=(g,g^{-1}h)$$
is smooth, and hence the following composition is smooth:
$$g\mapsto (g,e)\overset{F^{-1}}{\mapsto} (g,g^{-1})\mapsto g^{-1}.$$

Comment: Nice explanation! But $F^{-1}$ sends $(g,e)$ to $(g,g^{-1})$ (rather than $(e,g^{-1})$), right?

Comment: @OskarHenriksson Right; thanks. It is correct now.

Comment: Why is $F^{-1}$ automatically smooth?

Comment: @ラミタ Because we have shown that $F$ is a local diffeomorphism. It follows from the Inverse Function Theorem that a bijective local diffeomorphism is a diffeomorphism. See in Lee's book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (Second Edition)" the section on local diffeomorphisms starting on page 79. In particular, look at Theorem 4.5 and Proposition 4.6(f).

Comment: @Spenser Thanks, I got confused because in my course we don't assume diffeos to be smooth.