# A smooth manifold with a smooth multiplication is a Lie group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

> Let $G$ be a smooth (resp., continuous) manifold with a group structure s.t. the multiplication $\circ:G\times G\rightarrow G$ is smooth (resp., continuous). Show that the inversion $^{-1}:G\rightarrow G$ is smooth (resp., continuous) too.

This seems doubtful to me. I've never seen such a "reduced" definition of a Lie group in books. But I cannot build a counterexample. Do you know a one?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893031/reference-for-redundance-of-inversion-condition-for-lie-groups) is a proof (at least for the smooth part)

Comment: I don't see how to do just the continuous case though: how to show that the canonical map (called $F$ in the answer) is a homeomorphism?

Comment: The continuous case seems much trickier. I wonder if the solution to Hilbert's 5th problem says something here (every continuous group is a smooth Lie group)

Comment: @JoMo, I suppose in continuous case the statement is not valid at all.

Comment: @MaximNikitin: but building a counterexample is going to be really tricky, since it must necessarily be nonsmooth